# Explanation of difference in performance between CPLEX, Gurobi and FICO Xpress using interior point method (barrier) without crossover?

Tags: linear-programming, solver, barrier

I am working with a very large (stochastic) LP with the barrier algorithm without crossover. My model is implemented in Pyomo, and I have tried to use CPLEX, Gurobi and FICO Xpress to solve it. The solver settings in Pyomo are as follows:

For CPLEX:

```
opt = SolverFactory("cplex")
opt.options["lpmethod"] = 4
opt.options["barrier crossover"] = -1
results = opt.solve(instance)
```

For Gurobi:

```
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
opt.set_instance(instance)
opt.options["Crossover"]=0
opt.options["Method"]=2
results = opt.solve(instance, load_solutions=True)
results = opt.load_vars()
results = opt.load_duals()
```

For FICO Xpress:

```
opt = SolverFactory("xpress")
opt.options["defaultAlg"] = 4
opt.options["crossover"] = 0
results = opt.solve(instance)
```

All solvers find a solution, but with (very) varying speed:

- Gurobi finds a sub-optimal solution in 4593 s (9.98262837e+11) using 337 iterations
- FICO Xpress finds the optimal solution in 7981 s (9.98246410e+11) using 169 iterations
- CPLEX finds a sub-optimal solution in 40,178 s  (9.98250954e+11) using 258 iterations

My question is: Why is there such a huge difference between the solvers (especially comparing CPLEX and Gurobi)? What is going on in the different barrier algorithms?

Summary of log for CPLEX:

```
IBM(R) ILOG(R) CPLEX(R) Interactive Optimizer 12.8.0.0
Read time = 52.61 sec. (3283.43 ticks)
Objective sense      : Minimize
Variables            : 17684371
Objective nonzeros   : 7976817
Linear constraints   : 26929486  [Less: 25202826,  Equal: 1726660]
  Nonzeros           : 83463204
  RHS nonzeros       :  621453
Tried aggregator 1 time.
DUAL formed by presolve
Aggregator has done 14545 substitutions...
LP Presolve eliminated 8512063 rows and 3459945 columns.
Reduced LP has 14209881 rows, 21009396 columns, and 61814653 nonzeros.
Presolve time = 148.20 sec. (209740.04 ticks)
Parallel mode: using up to 24 threads for barrier.
***NOTE: Found 243 dense columns.
Number of nonzeros in lower triangle of A*A' = 268787475
Elapsed ordering time = 17.45 sec. (10000.00 ticks)
Using Nested Dissection ordering
Total time for automatic ordering = 376.13 sec. (209058.23 ticks)
Summary statistics for Cholesky factor:
  Threads                   = 24
  Rows in Factor            = 14210124
  Integer space required    = 145889976
  Total non-zeros in factor = 12261481354
  Total FP ops to factor    = 39156639536792
Total time on 24 threads = 40177.89 sec. (62234738.71 ticks)
Barrier - Non-optimal:  Objective =  9.9825095360e+11
Solution time = 40177.90 sec.  Iterations = 258
```

Summary of log for Xpress:

```
FICO Xpress Solver 64bit v8.5.0:
Problem Statistics
    26929486 (      0 spare) rows
    17684371 (      0 spare) structural columns
    83463204 (      0 spare) non-zero elements
Presolved problem has:
  18426768 rows     14805105 cols     59881674 elements
Barrier cache sizes : L1=32K L2=20480K
Using AVX support
Cores per CPU (CORESPERCPU): 12
Barrier starts, using up to 24 threads, 12 cores
Matrix ordering - Dense cols.:   6776   NZ(L): 485925484   Flops: 273369311062
Barrier method finished in 7874 seconds
Optimal solution found
Barrier solved problem
  169 barrier iterations in 7981s
Final objective                         : 9.982464100682021e+11
Max primal violation      (abs / rel) : 1.612e-03 / 1.612e-03
Max dual violation        (abs / rel) : 1.837e+02 / 7.381e+01
Max complementarity viol. (abs / rel) : 1.837e+02 / 1.675e-07
```

Summary of log for Gurobi:

```
Gurobi 8.0.0: 
Optimize a model with 26929485 rows, 17684370 columns and 83463203 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e-05, 4e+00]
  Objective range  [2e+00, 8e+06]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [1e-01, 2e+08]
Presolve removed 8527789 rows and 2871939 columns
Presolve time: 53.79s
Presolved: 18401696 rows, 14812431 columns, 59808411 nonzeros
Ordering time: 29.38s
Barrier statistics:
 Dense cols : 4607
 AA' NZ     : 6.262e+07
 Factor NZ  : 5.722e+08 (roughly 18.0 GBytes of memory)
 Factor Ops : 3.292e+11 (roughly 4 seconds per iteration)
 Threads    : 12
Barrier performed 337 iterations in 4592.92 seconds
Sub-optimal termination - objective 9.98262837e+11
```

Comment: Solution times are implementation dependent. Not sure it is possible to get a more detailed answer than this, as it would require an understanding of the underlying implementation specifics. Note that there are also large differences on an instance-by-instance basis, too (e.g., see [here](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/barrier.html))

Comment: What do you mean when you write 'implementation'-dependent? Do you mean how the barrier algorithm is implemented in the three different solvers? The underlying lp-files are exactly the same for these three instances.

Comment: Yes, exactly: there are several design choices that are not clear cut and work well under certain conditions while do not work well on others. There may be other differences too, such as in the data structures used, base algorithms (e.g. what kind of sorting is used), numerics, pre-processing intensity, etc. [Here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp/browser/trunk/Clp/src) is the source code of Clp, precurssor fo CPLEX, which gives an idea of the complexity involved in developing commercial solvers.

Comment: May be try to reduce the number of threads for Cplex? (Check your memory usage). You also may want to consider scaling your model a bit.

Comment: Yes, I will try. Have noticed CPLEX uses about double processing power and memory compared to Gurobi. What do you mean scaling? Like, divide the entire objective function by 1 000 000?

Comment: (1) Too many threads can cause the solver to use much more memory and also contention. For LP solvers there is a point where adding threads is not beneficial. (2) Bad scaling can be the result of using crazy units (e.g. cents instead of billions of dollars). Fixing this may require more than just dividing the objective by a constant.

Answer (score 2):

With CPLEX the factorization is much more expensive.

```
#FLOPS CPLEX  ~3.92e+13
#FLOPS Xpress ~2.73e+11
#FLOPS Gurobi ~3.29e+11
```

I've seen such discrepancy a few times for large-scale LPs. In most of these cases CPLEX made a bad decision to pass the dual to the optimizer

```
DUAL formed by presolve
```

Setting the PreDual parameter to -1 prevents that.